# Probability of Event if Another Occurs

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

An enemy that can drop loot has a 10% probability of spawning out of all enemies. Only one model type can drop loot out of 8 models (1/8). What is the probability of a specific enemy dropping loot, if they are the model that can drop loot? Would 0.1 + 0.125 = 22.5% chance be correct?

Comment: What's a model and an enemy?

Comment: it's nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Your description is a bit ambiguous and lacks details, but let me try to answer.

> What is the probability of a specific enemy dropping loot, if they are the model that can drop loot?

You said that "An enemy that can drop loot has a 10% probability of spawning out of all enemies.", so I guess that you answered yourself: it's 10% if by "probability of [...] dropping loot" you mean "probability of spawning out of all enemies". If they are not the same, your question does not contain such information.

An alternative reading of your question is that you are asking about the probability that you pick the model that can drop the loot ($1/8$) *and* it drops the loot ($1/10$). In such a case it's $1/10 \times 1/8 = 1/80$.

> Would 0.1 + 0.125 = 22.5% chance be correct?

Definitely not. We add the probabilities of mutually exclusive events (A or B). You are asking about their joint probability (A and B) which is a product if the events are [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) or conditional probability (depending on the interpretation, as described in the previous paragraphs).